# Subscripts in \sup and \inf showing at different heights in displaystyle

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

Consider this example: `\[\sup_{i\in I},\; \inf_{i\in I}\]`. Upon rendering in display mode `\[ \]`, the subscript in the supremum case is displayed significantly lower below the text than in the infimum. Is there a way to fix this? I know there exist packages that allow you to manually move stuff around, but I'm not familiar with them. Furthermore, why does this happen?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The difference in position is because of the descender on the "p", while "inf" has nothing below the baseline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subscript is lower with `\sup` than with `\inf` simply because the letter "p" goes below the baseline. You could change this behavior and define new commands where the subscript of `\sup` would be higher, or where the subscript of `\inf` would be lower.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\newsup}{\mathop{\smash{\mathrm{sup}}}}
\newcommand{\newinf}{\mathop{\mathrm{inf}\vphantom{\mathrm{sup}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Default:                            & \(\displaystyle \sup_{i\in I},\; \inf_{i\in I} \)    \\
Raised subscript in \verb|\sup|:    & \(\displaystyle \newsup_{i\in I},\; \inf_{i\in I} \) \\
Lowered subscript in \verb|\inf|:   & \(\displaystyle \sup_{i\in I},\; \newinf_{i\in I} \) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in both modified cases, it looks weird (at least in my opinion), since the subscript overlaps on the "p" in one case, and there is a lot of white space between `\inf` and its subscript in the other case. I agree that the default might not be entirely satisfying, but I think it's still the best.

Comment: I'd use a `\vphantom{\mathrm{f}}` also in `\newsup`.

Comment: @egreg It would indeed be a good idea to align eventual superscripts (however we don't see superscripts so often with inf or sup). But would it have an impact on the subscripts? Or something else, beside superscripts? I didn't think so, but you probably know better than me ;-)

Comment: I believe that `\mathstrut` would take care of both height and depth at the same time.

Comment: the \smash option actually works perfectly for my intended purpose- writing limsups and liminfs. The limit underneat is shifted to the left far enough that the p does not intersect. Therefore this accomplishes exactly what I wanted.